# Listing all items with rules in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, nosql

I have a firebase database where users can submit `posts`. If the post is submitted privately, other users can not read it.

See the database and the rules below:

```
// FIREBASE DATABASE:
{
  "posts" : {
    "-PaNtmNIFp9sTT549-Kn" : {
      "author" : "XXXYYY",
      "content" : "New post",
      "public" : true
    },
    "-PaNw0ak27MfcU5Vff1t" : {
      "author" : "XXXYYY",
      "content" : "Secret post",
      "public" : false
    },
    "-PaOPhX3SwRe2ThEFWJo" : {
      "author" : "XXXYYY",
      "content" : "another post",
      "public" : true
    }
  },
  "user-posts" : {
    "XXXYYY" : {
      "-PaNtmNIFp9sTT549-Kn" : true,
      "-PaNw0ak27MfcU5Vff1t" : true,
      "-PaOPhX3SwRe2ThEFWJo" : true
    }
  }
}

// RULES:
{
  "rules": {
    "posts": {
      "$post": {
         ".read": "auth !== null && data.child('public').val() === true || data.child('author').val() === auth.uid"
       }
    }
  }
}
```

This works fine, but only when I retrieve the items post by post:

```
// DOES NOT WORK
firebase.database().ref().child('posts').on('value', snap => {
  console.log(snap.val())
});

// DOES WORK
var children = ["-PaNtmNIFp9sTT549-Kn", "-PaNw0ak27MfcU5Vff1t", "-PaOPhX3SwRe2ThEFWJo"];
children.forEach(function(child) {
  rootRef.child(child).on('value', snap => {
    console.log(snap.val())
  })
})
```

I guess that [Rules are not Filters](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/guide/securing-data.html#section-filter), right? Then my question becomes:

- How do I hint the user with the right entities to look for? Should I make a separate node with all public posts keys, ie called `publicPosts`?
- If I still want to be able to sort queries on public posts by, say, their content, how do I go about doing this? Simply by duplicating all data that could be relevant for a query in the new node `publicPosts`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A list with the keys of public posts is indeed one option. The other options is to create a separate top-level node with the complete public posts.

And indeed: to be able to sort on data, that data must be readable to the user. If you just want to order them by a timestamp, you could put that timestamp as the value (instead of the `true` you have now). But for more elaborate queries you'll need to duplicate more data. At some point you'll like be better off duplicating the entire post.